# How to sort from smallest to largest the first row and the first column of a table in R

Tags: r, sorting

In the attached table I want to reorder from lowest to highest the values of the variable X and those of the variable Y, that is to say, that the variable X appears like this: 3,5,9 and 10 and Y:3,5,8 and 10.

These are the codes, with which I have generated the table, called "public":[image]

```
lim <- sample(2:10, 4)

lim1 <- sample(3:10, 4)

create_table <- function() {
  n_a <- sample(10:25,1)
  n_b <- 30-n_a
  n_c <- sample(5:18,1)
  n_d <- 20-n_c
  P3 <- rmultinom(1, n_a, prob=c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1))
  P4 <- rmultinom(1, n_b, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3))
  P5 <- rmultinom(1, n_a, prob=c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1))
  P6 <- rmultinom(1, n_b, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3))
  matrix(c(P3, P4, P5, P6), nrow = 4, ncol = 4,
          dimnames = list(c(lim[1], lim[2] ,lim[3],lim[4]),
           c(lim1[1] ,lim1[2], lim1[3], lim1[4])))
}

public <- create_table()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `public[order(rownames(public)), order(colnames(public))]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
library(stringr)
do.call('[', c(list(public), 
                  lapply(dimnames(public), str_sort, numeric = TRUE)))
  6 7 8 10
3 2 4 0  0
5 7 2 8  8
6 3 2 3  3
8 1 5 6  6
```

This code could be written as:

```
public[str_sort(rownames(public), numeric = TRUE), 
       str_sort(colnames(public), numeric = TRUE)]
```

---

```
public[order(as.numeric(rownames(public))), order(as.numeric(colnames(public)))]
  6 7 8 10
3 2 4 0  0
5 7 2 8  8
6 3 2 3  3
8 1 5 6  6
```

Comment: Perfect. Above, I have posted the result.